# Questions about STM32F103C8T6 pins/button

Tags: stm32, pins, button

Recently I bought this STM32F103C8T6 minimum evaluation board [STM32F103C8T6](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/stm32f103c8t6-stm32-stm32f103-stm32f103c8-minimum-system-board-learning-board-evaluation-kit-stm32-development-board-core/32575826485.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.25.JZrNra&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10068_10209_5400015_10304_10307_10301_10137_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10054_5370015_10059_100031_10099_5380015_10103_10102_5410015_5430015_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_5390015_10177_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10315_10078_10079_10210_10073_5420015,searchweb201603_4,ppcSwitch_2&btsid=1fce1353-8cbb-4d86-b646-860776b2bb7f&algo_expid=3a521626-401a-4641-be18-9d0ba6c387e3-3&algo_pvid=3a521626-401a-4641-be18-9d0ba6c387e3), see picture below.

I have some questions about it (see (small) numbers in the picture):

1. Button S1 is RST (reset button), however, what is the function of button S2? Is it connected to some GPIO and if so, which one?
2. These three pins do not have a mark, what could be the GPIO port/pin numbers of these pins?
3. What is this 'slot' for?
4. What is the use of this jumper? (I did not dare to experiment with it)

[image: STM32F103C8T6 eval board]

Comment: I looked at your link and I could not find any technical documents. Unless you can provide a link to a datasheet for the board or at least a schematic, it's unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: Ask the vendor for documentation.  We are not Aliexpress's support site.

Comment: @PeterBennett I fully agree, I would think there might be more people having experience with this board (I'm quite new to STM32, being happy I could do a blink led via peripheral lib and STM in a few evenings trying).

Comment: -1 You've been here long enough to know better than to post a question without the necessary supporting data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree (after reading the answers I could have found it myself probably too, or at least partly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a blurry, unsourced schematic online which appears to match with your board.](http://www.uctronics.com/download/U4299.jpg) The parts I can read suggest that:

1. Button S2 is connected to PA0. (The pin is grounded when the button is pressed.)
2. Starting from the end of that header closest to S2 and moving upwards, the pins are:

   - 3V3
   - GND
   - VBAT
   - PC13
   - PC14
   - PC15
   - VDDA
   - PA0
   - PA1 (and so on)
3. As marked on the PCB, it looks like it's for some specific I2C OLED screen breakout.
4. That jumper is connected to BOOT0. It can be used to control whether the microcontroller boots normally from flash or runs a bootloader from an internal ROM by strapping it to 3V3 or GND, both of which are on adjacent pins.

Incidentally, the board appears to have an I2C EEPROM (AT24C04, I think?) on it as well. It's marked as U4 on the PCB.

Comment: Thanks for finding that ... I also tried to search something like that, but couldn't find the one with two buttons (and only searched after asking this question somewhere else), and I had a hard time reading it.

Answer (score 1):

> Recently I bought this STM32F103C8T6 minimum evaluation board STM32F103C8T6

When buying from AliExpress, ebay etc. there is often a lack of technical support. Therefore if that vendor is unable to answer your questions, *you* have to be prepared to do the reverse-engineering of the device to answer your own questions. That is one reason why the devices are so cheap. If you want better support, there are vendors who provide it (not necessarily on those selling platforms) but you pay more.

> 1.Button S1 is RST (reset button), however, what is the function of button S2? Is it connected to some GPIO and if so, which one?

Follow the PCB traces to find out where that switch is connected to. When you find that, if you can't understand its *function*, then that seems a suitable question for EE.SE.

> 2.These three pins do not have a mark, what could be the GPIO port/pin numbers of these pins?

Turn over the PCB - they are marked on the reverse side.

> 3.What is this 'slot' for?

Considering the label "OLED" nearby, I expect it is designed for a proprietary OLED display module.

> 4.What is the use of this jumper? (I did not dare to experiment with it)

The label `BT0` is likely connected to the STM32 `BOOT0` pin. That fits with the pins on each side of `BT0` being 3.3V and 0V, to allow you pull `BOOT0` high or low, depending on which memory you want the STM32 to boot from.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I agree that I cannot expect much ... reason is too that I am just trying things, afraid to break items, and even more important, I'm not sure what I 'need' for my hobby project, it's more about learning.

Feeling stupid about not having turned the PCB.